# GPG/GnuPG secret key passphrase recovery and/or .gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/ file format

Tags: gnupg, data-recovery, passphrase, recovery

Bad news: I forgot a GnuPG secret key passphrase.

Good news: I do know the words it is constructed of.  So, I can easily use `john` or similar to recover (too many combinations to do it manually, though).

Problem: The secret key is not in the `secring.gpg` format that `john` understands, but in some [new format](https://www.gnupg.org/faq/whats-new-in-2.1.html#nosecring), apparently distributed across 2 files, in

```
~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/0123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF01234567.key
```

and

```
~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/123456789ABCDEF0123456789ABCDEF012345678.key
```

(files renamed for this question, obviously) created within the timespan of a few seconds - could be pubkey and seckey, if so which one is which?

Could someone please help, maybe by telling me how to extract the (still locked) seckey from these files without a passphrase?  An ASCII armor format would be ideal.

Alternatively, maybe someone knows how to feed these files to `john` directly?

On a related note: Can I enforce the `secring.gpg` format in `GnuPG`? I share `/home` between systems with different versions of `GnuPG` and don't want to duplicate key files.

Thanks.

PS: Since I already have files encrypted with the key a revocation and replacement would not be a viable solution.

Comment: Did you try `gpg --list-packets 123.key` to see what's inside?

Comment: @Arminius: `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

Comment: Apparently, `gpg` cannot understand these files, only `gpg-agent` (a daemon) can. Passphrases are read by a third, separate program `pinentry`. Could it be more complicated?

Comment: The `gpg` command doesn't understand the new private key database format, you need to use `gpg2` command instead.

Comment: @LieRyan Thanks. Since I have GnuPG 2.1 installed, `gpg` is just a link to `gpg2`, anyway. According to the docs (link in my question above), GnuPG can read the new secret keys only through `gpg-agent` (a concept change), not through `gpg`.

Comment: Have I asked this in the wrong forum? Or do people not want to help hackers (whether it be me if I lied and the key was not mine, or by providing a public answer to a hacking-type question)?

Comment: This wasn't the wrong forum to ask. I think your question has a limited number of people that can answer this with any authority*. (e.g. Needs to know internals of `gpg-agent`, how to use `john` in a not yet supported way, and how to crack an encryption that wasn't designed to be) [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) would be the only other SE site better qualified to answer this.   

*_I don't consider myself an authority, I'm just wildly speculating a possible solution_.

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a guess at these, but I have no easy way to test if these are actually possible.

**Easiest:** [Nasty](https://www.vanheusden.com/nasty/) and [crackgpg](https://github.com/pfichtner/crackgpg) have been designed for this purpose. If one of them has been updated to support this new format, try it.

**Harder:** The file format is documented in [gnupg/agent/keyformat.txt](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=agent/keyformat.txt;hb=HEAD). Can you get something like `john` to try your wordlist until it gets a `(` as the first character?

Comment: Thanks. I tried nasty before but it is just too old for the "new" format. I am assuming the same for crackgpg. Will have a look, though. The format documentation you have linked to is from the future - apparently another change is planned already. I am unsure what you mean by using john - which encryption algorithm (I suppose john knows many?) would I tell john to use?

Comment: For keyformat.txt, look at an earlier version in the repository, or the source of your currently installed version on your machine. (With an RPM based distro, you'd get tgr SRPM)

Comment: I missed some words on the john answer. It appears to have a DYNAMIC mode that would let you customize what its trying to crack. I'll try to work out if thats practical and edit links into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A developer of John the Ripper has posted a program that can be used with the mask mode of JtR to crack this format. It has to be linked against libgcrypt from GnuPG.

It is available [here](https://github.com/magnumripper/JohnTheRipper/issues/847#issuecomment-270948142).